# Using Select-String -NotMatch in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to find .nfo files that aren't XML.  It seems to mostly work, but some of the files are XML and are still being listed.  One example has this for the first line:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>`

Here is my code.  I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
Get-ChildItem "c:\*.nfo" -recurse | ForEach-Object {
    if (Get-Content -LiteralPath $_ -First 1 | Select-String -Pattern 'xml' -NotMatch) 
    {
        Write-Output $_.Fullname
    }
}
```

I don't care if they are properly formatted XML files so I am just using the first line to test.

Comment: `-LiteralPath $_` -> `-LiteralPath $_.FullName`

Comment: A different option to Mathias' would be to pipe the FileInfo object to `Get-Content`, the PSPath property would be used as an alias for LiteralPath. `if (-not ($_ | Get-Content -TotalCount 1).Contains('xml'))`. Select-String shouldn't be needed as you've already got the first line anyway, and `-First` is an alias so using the main parameter name `-TotalCount` may be better practise.

Comment: I guess some of your xml files start with an empty line. Please try to create an [mcve]: remove the out loop, and show the first lines of your failing xml file in the question.

Comment: @iRon  I thought that two and tried getting the first two lines but it was the same result.  I also looked at one of those files in Notepad++ showing all characters and there is no extra characters like a line feed.  I will change the code to output the first line and see what it shows.

Comment: The answer #1 below gave errors due to not using LiteralPath. When using LiteralPath it yielded the exact same results as my code. Some of the filenames have brackets.

Comment: When I use -Simplematch I get the opposite of what I want.  I suspect -Notmatch works differently.  The documentation is light on that. Maybe I have to reformulate this.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Get-ChildItem "c:\*.nfo" -recurse | Where-Object{(Get-Content $_ -First 1) -notmatch 'xml'}
```